# Behaviour of Mesos when using cgroups for Spark

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, cgroups

I was wondering what the behaviour of Spark in fine-grained mode on Mesos would be, when cgroups are enabled.

One concern is the following: when I use Mesos+spark without cgroups, it already shows that the actual spark executor process uses at least 10% more memory, than what it promised to Mesos it would use. When enabling cgroups, would it kill the Spark-executors?

Second, how is file-cache handled? Spark relies heavily on file-cache. Is file-cache accounted to the amount of memory in Mesos? Probably not, but could we influence this? So for example, ideally I want Spark to use 8GB in total, of which 5GB should be used for the java process -- assuming that spark plays nicely and does not grow beyond 5GB -- and 3GB should be used as file-cache (max).

I hope someone has experience with this, because in order to test these things myself I would have to go through a lot of support requests from our cluster sysadmin, as cgroups rely on root credentials at one point - and I'd hate it to be in vain without having asked others.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it seems you've got something mixed up with how cgroups work. The executor simply would not (,and it indeed does, as I can confirm) be able to allocate more memory than the cgroups would allow. So Mesos would not actually act as an process killer or anything*. But, some types of programs would indeed break on being unable to allocate more memory and it depends on the program if it then quits, or is able to run fine, but perhaps with less memory and/or performance.

For your second question, there don't seem to be any configuration settings in order to influence the actual cgroup memory amount. There seems to be a 1-to-1 mapping between the executor memory setting and what Spark gets from Mesos. However, I do think there is a hidden factor, because I can see Spark asks for roughly 5.8GB, but actually I set the executor memory to 5GB. (I'll update the ticket once I can find this hidden factor of probably 15% in the source code.)

Update, the setting you'd want is `spark.mesos.executor.memoryOverhead`. You can give a number in MegaBytes which is added to the executor memory as the total memory which will be used as Mesos resource, and thus as a cgroup memory limit.

*=Update2, actually cgroups by default does kill processes which grow beyond the control group's limit. I can confirm that the `memory.oom_control` in `/cgroups/memory/x/` is set to '0' (which counter-intuitively is enabled). However in the case of Spark, it is the aformentioned 10-15% overhead which gives enough leeway to not encounter OOM.